# How to replace a field in a lambda function which is being deployed using CF template

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

My lambda function/code resides in a S3 bucket.
The lambda function has a piece of code which looks like:

RoleArn = "XXXX:accountid"

The RoleArn will change every time I deploy to a different child account.

I am using a Cloudformation template which has:

```
FunctiontToUse:
  Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
  Properties:        
    Code:
      S3Bucket: 'bucket-name'
      S3Key: 's3key.zip'
    Description: Description
    FunctionName: FunctionName
    Handler: FunctionName.lambda_handler
    MemorySize: 1024
    Role: role
    Runtime: python3.6
    Timeout: 5
```

If I try using "${accountid}" it doesn;t work. But this works when I paste the function in the CF template and don't use the bucket.

Please advise.

PS: unable to format the cf template above.

Comment: If you want the account number from within the Lambda function, use context. invoked_function_arn. This will contain the account number. Exact line of code will be" `context.invoked_function_arn.split(":")[4]` Or, use `sts_client.get_caller_identity()['Account']` to get the account number. Otherwise, send the account number as an environment variable to the Lambda function

Comment: You can pass an environment variable to a lambda function, and reference that in the code. as `os.environ["yourvariablename"]` in your function.